# gridview linkbutton CommandArgument value not changing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid view with a list of data and a LinkButton to delete the row.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridApartment" EmptyDataText="No Records Found" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="0"
                            AllowPaging="true" ShowFooter="false" PageSize="15" Width="100%" OnPageIndexChanging="gridApartment_PageIndexChanging"
                            CssClass="mGrid"
                            OnRowDeleting="gridApartment_RowDeleting" OnRowCommand="gridApartment_RowCommand">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
                            <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Building">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="BuildingName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BuildingName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="25%"></HeaderStyle>
                                </asp:TemplateField>


                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" CssClass="aDelete" ToolTip="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="delete" OnClientClick=' javascript:return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?"); '
                                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RoomDetailsId") %>'>Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderStyle Width="8%"></HeaderStyle>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

                            </Columns>

                        </asp:GridView>
```

onload data filled by this code

```
gridApartment.DataSource = masterManager.GetAllRooms();
gridApartment.DataBind();
```

now i have a search box, and when i search, the filters result will get bind by this code.

```
gridApartment.DataSource = conobj.GetSearchDetails("usp_RoomDetailsSearch", "@SearchName", txtSearchterm.Text.Trim());
gridApartment.DataBind();
```

for delete the code is

```
protected void gridApartment_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "delete")
        {
            var masterManager = new MasterEntryManager();

            int res = masterManager.DeletRoom(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

            Search();
        }
    }
```

when the first time the grid get loaded e.CommandArgument has the right ID and i can delete the right row. But when i search and re bind the gridview, the e.CommandArgument value is not updated with new ID. It still return the same ID which is loaded first on page load.

For eg:

1. when the grid is first loaded, when i try delete the first row, e.CommandArgument has an ID say, 1001 and I deleted the record with ID 1001.
2. Now I load the gridview second time. Now the 1st row linkbutton e.CommandArgument has ID 1500.
3. I perform a search and the result grid has only 5 rows
4. Now i try to delete the first row, the expected linkbutton e.CommandArgument ID is say 2001, but i get the linkbutton e.CommandArgument ID as 1500, the value of first row ID when the gridview first loaded

Id is not get updated.
How can I get the updated e.CommandArgument value.?

Comment: As you are using `LinkButton`, try by using `OnClick` event instead of `CommandName`, in `OnClick` event try this `(sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument`

Comment: I write the OnClick event. But the ID value is not get updating after search and refilling the gridview.

Comment: Then check are you getting correct id in `CommandArument` by viewsource or in debugger window.

Comment: No. I'm not getting the correct ID in CommandArument. The value of CommandArument is not getting updated after the search. The value is same as the one it get assign when the grid first loads.

Comment: You might be getting that from your `DataSource`, you may need to check what data you are getting back from `DataBase` (from methods which supply data to GridView)

Comment: I checked the datasource which is a datatable. In that the ID is getting correctly.

Comment: There is no mistake in your posted code and if you used `OnClick` event also it should work as expected, may be there is some other problem somewhere in your code. Try debuging

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68871/discussion-between-sharon-and-bharadwaj).

Answer (score 0):

Counter to expectations, the CommandArgument is not associated with the control that does the post back.  Rather, the DataSource is returned as part of the ViewState, and the CommandArgument is referenced by the index of the control.  If either the GridView or DataSource change, the index will no longer be correct.

You need to make sure that the GridView and DataSource are not updated prior referencing the CommandArgument, but then updated after the delete (it looks like you have this part).  Remember that the post back event occurs after the page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        gridApartment.DataSource = masterManager.GetAllRooms();
        gridApartment.DataBind();
    }
}
```