# GridView LinkButton not changing the value of CommandArgument after search in C#

Tags: c#, gridview, asp.net-web-api

I found a similar question: [gridview linkbutton CommandArgument value not changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961020/gridview-linkbutton-commandargument-value-not-changing)

Comment: Can you post the `Page_Load` and your search method (only the part affecting the gridview)?

Comment: It will be better if you post these in the question instead of comment. I suspect that you have populated the gridview in the `Page_Load` with no `IsPostback` check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are not checking the `IsPostBack` property before populating your gridview *first time*. Try this:

First, wrap your first-time gridview populating with a method:

```
private void PopulateGridview()
{
     string cmdstr= "SELECT DriverID,DriverEmail,Availability FROM tblDriver";
     gv1.DataSource = getall(cmdstr,con);
     gv1.DataBind();
}
```

Now, call it in the `Page_Load()` this way:

```
protected void Page_Load()
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        PopulateGridview();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you .Its my bad ... didnt check the postback thing before :)